# How to disable `Microsoft Outlook`'s keybindings in macOS

Tags: keybindings, microsoft

I am using `Microsoft Outlook` in macOS. Is it possible to disable its keybindings such as <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> for select all, since I am using that binding for something else.

Basically, I just want `Microsoft Outlook` to see the default keybindings that `macOS` using.

---

Please note that I am using [Emacs key bindings using Karabiner](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/?q=emacs).

```
Key Bindings (control+keys)

control+bfnp    arrow keys
control+d   forward delete
control+h   delete
control+i   tab
control+[   escape
control+m   return
control+v   page down
control+a   (Microsoft Office)  home
control+e   (Microsoft Office)  end
```

Comment: Based on my understanding you want to reassign keybinding(s) not to disable it. However, bear in mind that Command-A is macOS built-in keyboard shortcut which works globally ([Cut, copy, paste, and other common shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236#copy))

Comment: I am using emacs keybindings is system-wide, like `command-a` goes to beginning of the line or ecommand-e` goes to end of the current line and so on but none of them works under Windows products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution with Karabiner

Add this to the directory `~/.config/karabiner/assets/complex_modifications` as a .json file with whatever unique filename you would like.

```json
{
    "title": "Microsoft Outlook rules",
    "rules": [
        {
            "description": "Microsoft Outlook Unmap command-A",
            "manipulators": [
                {
                    "type": "basic",
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "a",
                        "modifiers": {
                            "mandatory": ["command"],
                            "optional": ["caps_lock"]
                        }
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "key_code": "home"
                        }
                    ],
                    "conditions": [
                        {
                            "type": "frontmost_application_if",
                            "bundle_identifiers": ["^com\\.microsoft\\.Outlook$"]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

After you do this you will need to enable the complex modification by going to Karabiner-Elements Preferences > Complex Modifications > Rules > Add and picking it from the list.

## More Info and Tools

[Here is a link to the documentation for writing your own complex modifications.](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/json/typical-complex-modifications-examples/)

If you want to do this for another application you can add a regex for the bundle ID of the app to the "bundle_identifiers" JSON entry. An easy way to get the bundle ID for an app is to use [my Alfred workflow](https://github.com/yomotherboard/yoAlfred/blob/main/Code/Get%20Bundle%20ID.alfredworkflow). Just open Alfred and type `bundle <application_name>` and it will give you autocomplete results from the applications you have installed. It copies the bundle ID for the application to your clipboard.

You can also use defaults to get the bundle ID: \

```bsh
defaults read <path_to_the_application>/Contents/Info CFBundleIdentifier
```

**P.S. If you want to make your own complex modifications I would actually suggest using [Goku.](https://github.com/yqrashawn/GokuRakuJoudo)**

Comment: Is it also possible to apply this to all Windows producs like windows powerpoint, word and so on?

Comment: @alper yes, just get the bundle IDs of the apps using the Alfred workflow I linked to or the defaults command. Then add it (as a regex) to the "bundle_identifiers" json entry. so like: "bundle_identifiers": ["^com\\.microsoft\\.Outlook$", "^com\\.microsoft\\.someappname$"]

Comment: @alper Now that I think about it, if you want to do this for all Microsoft apps, you could probably just change it to: "bundle_identifiers": ["^com\\.microsoft\\..*$"].
I just replaced 'Outlook' with '.*' which is regex for "any sequence of characters" in case you weren't sure.

Comment: @alper based on your prompt I'm wondering it you wanted to map this command to something else for Microsoft Office so let me know if you want that. The code I would just disable "command-a" completely. It is possible to rebind it to basically whatever you want though.

Comment: Yes! I want to rebind `command-a` to home button if possible

Comment: @alper added this to the json code in the answer